# Redirect 301 not working with php variable in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have redirect from as bellow.

Redirect From:-

```
http://www.example.in/projects.php?proj_id=24&flats-in-ambegaon-pune-viva-phase-3
```

Redirect To:-

```
http://www.example.in/projects.php?proj_id=24&nirman-viva-phase-3
```

I have tried bellow snippet code but this is not working.so any one will guide me for right redirection.

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]&)*proj_id=124(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]&)*flats-in-ambegaon-pune-viva-phase-3(&|$)
RewriteRule ^projects\.php?proj_id=24&nirman-viva-phase-3? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /projects\.php\?proj_id=24&flats-in-ambegaon-pune-viva-phase-3    [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.in/projects.php?proj_id=24&nirman-viva-phase-3 [L,R]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this.

Answer (score 4):

Please Try to following and I have tested it :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^proj_id=24.*$ http://www.example.in/projects.php?proj_id=24&flats-in-ambegaon-pune-viva-phase-3/1-2-bhk-apartments-for-sale-in-ambegaon-pune-amenities.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @Ferrybig for suggestion I have added clear description of my answer.